# Error Building OpenFlow project in OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, veins, openflow

I downloaded an openflow for OMNeT 5.5.1 and inet 3.6.6 from the following link:
https://github.com/CoRE-RG/OpenFlow

When I build the project it could not create **libopenflow_dbg.dll** file, and it gives the following errors:

`make[1]: *** [Makefile:164: ../out/clang-release/src/libopenflow.dll] Error 1`

Answer (score 0):

The log shows that you try to build project in release mode. Therefore change the mode to debug (i.e. right-click on project and select `Build Configuraions` | `Set Active` | `debug`). Do the same for `INET`.

If errors will continue to occur set verbose output by opening `Properties` of the project | `C/C++ Build` | `Behavior` and in the `Build` field add `V=1` at the end. Then build project, and go to the first error in the log, and insert this error in your question.

Comment: But actually this error says nothing... Are there any errors earlier?

Comment: I have not done anything yet. I have just imported projects into OMNET++ and built them.

Comment: Do clean, then set debug mode as active, add V=1, and build project. Then show us the first error which occurs in log.